# Alarm does not go off if USB is disconnected

Tags: android, usb, alarmmanager

In my Application I use a repeating alarm. If the device (Trekstor SurfTab breeze 7.0 with Android 4.0.4) is connected to debug the application, everything works fine. As soon as I disconnect the device, no more alarm is going off.
To be sure this is an alarm issue I just created a simple example app.

Sample-Activity that just creates the alarm:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (am != null) {

            final Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);

            // check if this intent already exists
            if (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) == null) {
                am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(30),
                        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alarm-Receiver:

```
    public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        Log.d("AlarmReceiver", "onReceive");
        final File mainDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "AlarmTest");
        final File file = new File(mainDir, "alarmtest.txt");
        try {
            new FileWriter(file, true).append(new Date() + "\n").close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("AlarmReceiver", "Error writing alarmtest.txt", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="ch.rse.alarmtest"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="ch.rse.alarmtest.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />
</application>
```

This is what logcat says:

```
01-18 13:26:20.170: D/AlarmReceiver(4890): onReceive
01-18 13:26:50.170: D/AlarmReceiver(4890): onReceive
01-18 13:27:01.660: D/lights(183): ro.product.lights =65
01-18 13:27:01.660: D/lights(183): bright =97
01-18 13:27:01.670: D/lights(183): ro.product.lights =65
01-18 13:27:01.670: D/lights(183): bright =92
01-18 13:27:01.690: D/lights(183): ro.product.lights =65
01-18 13:27:01.690: D/lights(183): bright =88
01-18 13:27:01.700: D/lights(183): ro.product.lights =65
01-18 13:27:01.700: D/lights(183): bright =83
01-18 13:27:01.720: D/lights(183): ro.product.lights =65
01-18 13:27:01.720: D/lights(183): bright =79
01-18 13:27:01.740: D/lights(183): ro.product.lights =65
01-18 13:27:01.740: D/lights(183): bright =74
01-18 13:27:01.750: D/lights(183): ro.product.lights =65
01-18 13:27:01.750: D/lights(183): bright =70
01-18 13:27:01.770: D/lights(183): ro.product.lights =65
01-18 13:27:01.770: D/lights(183): bright =65
01-18 13:27:01.780: D/lights(183): ro.product.lights =65
01-18 13:27:01.780: D/lights(183): bright =65
01-18 13:27:01.800: D/lights(183): ro.product.lights =65
01-18 13:27:01.800: D/lights(183): bright =65
01-18 13:27:01.820: D/lights(183): ro.product.lights =65
01-18 13:27:01.820: D/lights(183): bright =65
01-18 13:27:01.830: D/lights(183): ro.product.lights =65
01-18 13:27:01.830: D/lights(183): bright =65
01-18 13:27:01.850: D/lights(183): ro.product.lights =65
01-18 13:27:01.850: D/lights(183): bright =65
01-18 13:27:01.870: D/lights(183): ro.product.lights =65
01-18 13:27:01.870: D/lights(183): bright =65
01-18 13:27:01.880: D/lights(183): ro.product.lights =65
01-18 13:27:01.880: D/lights(183): bright =65
01-18 13:27:01.900: D/lights(183): ro.product.lights =65
01-18 13:27:01.900: D/lights(183): bright =65
01-18 13:27:01.910: D/lights(183): ro.product.lights =65
01-18 13:27:01.910: D/lights(183): bright =65
01-18 13:27:01.930: D/lights(183): ro.product.lights =65
01-18 13:27:01.930: D/lights(183): bright =65
01-18 13:27:08.660: D/lights(183): ro.product.lights =65
01-18 13:27:08.660: D/lights(183): bright =65
01-18 13:27:08.680: D/lights(183): ro.product.lights =65
01-18 13:27:08.680: D/lights(183): bright =65
01-18 13:27:08.690: D/lights(183): ro.product.lights =65
01-18 13:27:08.690: D/lights(183): bright =65
01-18 13:27:08.710: D/lights(183): ro.product.lights =65
01-18 13:27:08.710: D/lights(183): bright =65
01-18 13:27:08.710: D/SensorHAL(183): +__control_activate: handle=0 enabled=0
01-18 13:27:08.710: D/SensorHAL(183): Active sensors=00000000, real=00000000
01-18 13:27:08.710: D/SensorHAL(183): +__control_set_delay: ns=66667000
01-18 13:27:08.730: D/SurfaceFlinger(168): About to give-up screen, flinger = 0xaff918
01-18 13:27:08.730: E/libEGL(168): validate_display:188 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
01-18 13:27:13.730: V/TransportControlView(183): Create TCV com.android.internal.widget.TransportControlView@41339418
01-18 13:27:13.830: D/dalvikvm(183): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1219K, 19% free 10550K/12935K, paused 58ms
01-18 13:27:13.850: V/LockScreen(183): updateResources(Context context)
01-18 13:27:13.860: V/LockScreen(183): Catch Exception
01-18 13:27:13.940: I/WindowManager(183): MediaPlayer.is not PlayingVideo
01-18 13:27:14.000: I/TabletStatusBar(249): DISABLE_CLOCK: yes
01-18 13:27:14.040: D/dalvikvm(249): GC_CONCURRENT freed 398K, 36% free 7845K/12103K, paused 2ms+3ms
01-18 13:27:20.170: D/AlarmReceiver(4890): onReceive
01-18 13:27:50.170: D/AlarmReceiver(4890): onReceive
01-18 13:28:04.580: D/dalvikvm(2717): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-18 13:28:04.580: D/dalvikvm(518): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-18 13:28:04.580: D/dalvikvm(2446): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-18 13:28:04.580: D/dalvikvm(317): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-18 13:28:04.580: D/dalvikvm(407): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-18 13:28:04.580: D/dalvikvm(437): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-18 13:28:04.580: D/dalvikvm(346): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-18 13:28:04.580: D/dalvikvm(865): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-18 13:28:04.580: D/dalvikvm(2703): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-18 13:28:04.580: D/dalvikvm(2762): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-18 13:28:04.580: D/dalvikvm(2730): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-18 13:28:04.580: D/dalvikvm(2797): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-18 13:28:04.580: D/dalvikvm(249): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-18 13:28:04.580: D/dalvikvm(3997): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-18 13:28:04.580: D/dalvikvm(330): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-18 13:28:04.580: D/dalvikvm(2688): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-18 13:28:04.580: D/dalvikvm(183): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-18 13:28:04.580: D/dalvikvm(362): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-18 13:28:04.580: D/dalvikvm(422): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-18 13:28:04.580: D/dalvikvm(4752): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-18 13:28:04.580: V/UsbDeviceManager(183): now time is Jan. 18 01:28:04:1358512084 nachm.
01-18 13:28:04.580: V/UsbDeviceManager(183): Delay time at Jan. 18 01:28:09:1358512089 nachm.  to send DISCONNECTED massage
01-18 13:28:04.590: D/dalvikvm(4772): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-18 13:28:04.590: D/dalvikvm(4890): Debugger has detached; object registry had 2519 entries
01-18 13:28:09.600: I/DynamicPManagerService(183): setCpuFrequnecyPolicy flag :2
01-18 13:28:09.600: V/UsbDeviceManager(183): now time is Jan. 18 01:28:09:1358512089 nachm.
01-18 13:28:09.600: D/UsbDeviceManager(183): disable UsbDeviceManager wakelock wlref = 1
01-18 13:33:16.985: D/AlarmReceiver(4890): onReceive
01-18 13:33:16.995: W/NetworkStats(183): found non-monotonic values; saving to dropbox
01-18 13:33:17.015: D/SensorHAL(183): +__control_activate: handle=0 enabled=1
01-18 13:33:17.015: D/SensorHAL(183): Active sensors=00000001, real=00000001
01-18 13:33:17.015: D/SensorHAL(183): +__control_set_delay: ns=200000000
01-18 13:33:17.015: D/SensorHAL(183): +__control_set_delay: ns=66667000
01-18 13:33:17.035: I//system/bin/memsicd(165): Algorithm Library Info:
01-18 13:33:17.035: I//system/bin/memsicd(165): Build date: 0d-01-12, 0d:21:11
01-18 13:33:17.035: I//system/bin/memsicd(165): NVM block size: 26
01-18 13:33:17.035: I//system/bin/memsicd(165): Version: 0100
01-18 13:33:17.035: I//system/bin/memsicd(165): Auto-Calibration: 1
01-18 13:33:17.035: I//system/bin/memsicd(165): CompassLib init result: 0
01-18 13:33:17.045: W/NetworkStats(183): found non-monotonic values; saving to dropbox
01-18 13:33:17.065: W/PowerUI(249): unknown intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED flg=0x10000010 }
01-18 13:33:17.065: I/StorageNotification(249): UMS connection changed to false (media state mounted)
01-18 13:33:17.165: D/dalvikvm(183): GC_CONCURRENT freed 628K, 16% free 10933K/12935K, paused 3ms+8ms
01-18 13:33:17.175: D/lights(183): ro.product.lights =65
01-18 13:33:17.175: D/lights(183): bright =65
01-18 13:33:17.175: I/WindowManager(183): Lock screen displayed!
01-18 13:33:17.185: D/lights(183): ro.product.lights =65
01-18 13:33:17.185: D/lights(183): bright =65
01-18 13:33:17.205: D/lights(183): ro.product.lights =65
01-18 13:33:17.205: D/lights(183): bright =65
01-18 13:33:17.225: D/lights(183): ro.product.lights =65
01-18 13:33:17.225: D/lights(183): bright =65
01-18 13:33:17.235: D/SurfaceFlinger(168): Screen about to return, flinger = 0xaff918
01-18 13:33:17.235: D/lights(183): ro.product.lights =65
01-18 13:33:17.235: D/lights(183): bright =65
01-18 13:33:17.265: D/lights(183): ro.product.lights =65
01-18 13:33:17.265: D/lights(183): bright =65
01-18 13:33:17.265: W/ThrottleService(183): unable to find stats for iface rmnet0
01-18 13:33:17.275: D/lights(183): ro.product.lights =65
01-18 13:33:17.275: D/lights(183): bright =65
01-18 13:33:17.295: D/lights(183): ro.product.lights =65
01-18 13:33:17.295: D/lights(183): bright =65
01-18 13:33:17.305: D/lights(183): ro.product.lights =65
01-18 13:33:17.305: D/lights(183): bright =65
01-18 13:33:17.325: D/lights(183): ro.product.lights =65
01-18 13:33:17.325: D/lights(183): bright =68
01-18 13:33:17.345: D/lights(183): ro.product.lights =65
01-18 13:33:17.345: D/lights(183): bright =74
01-18 13:33:17.355: D/lights(183): ro.product.lights =65
01-18 13:33:17.355: D/lights(183): bright =81
01-18 13:33:17.375: D/lights(183): ro.product.lights =65
01-18 13:33:17.375: D/lights(183): bright =88
01-18 13:33:17.395: D/lights(183): ro.product.lights =65
01-18 13:33:17.395: D/lights(183): bright =95
01-18 13:33:17.405: D/lights(183): ro.product.lights =65
01-18 13:33:17.405: D/lights(183): bright =102
01-18 13:33:18.985: V/UsbDeviceManager(183): now time is Jan. 18 01:33:19:1358512399 nachm.
01-18 13:33:18.995: I/DynamicPManagerService(183): setCpuFrequnecyPolicy flag :1
01-18 13:33:18.995: V/UsbDeviceManager(183): now time is Jan. 18 01:33:19:1358512399 nachm.
01-18 13:33:18.995: D/UsbDeviceManager(183): enable UsbDeviceManager wakelock wlref = 0
01-18 13:33:19.085: V/UsbDeviceManager(183): now time is Jan. 18 01:33:19:1358512399 nachm.
01-18 13:33:19.095: D/ViewRootImpl(249): pckname = com.android.systemui
01-18 13:33:19.095: V/UsbDeviceManager(183): now time is Jan. 18 01:33:19:1358512399 nachm.
01-18 13:33:19.095: D/UsbDeviceManager(183): enable UsbDeviceManager wakelock wlref = 1
01-18 13:33:19.095: I/StorageNotification(249): UMS connection changed to false (media state mounted)
01-18 13:33:19.135: D/MtpService(437): addStorageLocked 65537 /mnt/sdcard
01-18 13:33:19.135: D/MtpService(437): addStorageLocked 196609 /mnt/inet
01-18 13:33:19.135: D/MtpService(437): starting MTP server in MTP mode
01-18 13:33:19.135: D/MtpService(437): addStorageLocked 196609 /mnt/inet
01-18 13:33:19.135: D/MtpService(437): addStorageLocked 65537 /mnt/sdcard
01-18 13:33:19.175: I/StorageNotification(249): UMS connection changed to false (media state mounted)
01-18 13:33:20.165: D/AlarmReceiver(4890): onReceive
01-18 13:33:38.425: V/LockScreen(183): onTrigger = 0
01-18 13:33:38.455: I/WindowManager(183): MediaPlayer.is not PlayingVideo
01-18 13:33:38.465: W/InputManagerService(183): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4126f1a0
01-18 13:33:38.495: I/TabletStatusBar(249): DISABLE_CLOCK: no
01-18 13:33:38.495: V/TabletStatusBar(249): setLightsOn(true)
01-18 13:33:44.375: D/dalvikvm(362): GC_CONCURRENT freed 421K, 35% free 8611K/13063K, paused 2ms+5ms
01-18 13:33:44.595: D/dalvikvm(362): GC_CONCURRENT freed 479K, 33% free 8819K/13063K, paused 2ms+5ms
01-18 13:33:44.685: D/dalvikvm(362): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 322K, 34% free 8694K/13063K, paused 29ms
01-18 13:33:44.695: I/dalvikvm-heap(362): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.799MB for 1286224-byte allocation
01-18 13:33:44.745: D/dalvikvm(362): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 24% free 9948K/13063K, paused 26ms
01-18 13:33:44.855: D/dalvikvm(362): GC_CONCURRENT freed 189K, 26% free 9780K/13063K, paused 2ms+10ms
01-18 13:33:45.085: D/dalvikvm(362): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1908K, 35% free 8596K/13063K, paused 38ms
01-18 13:33:45.085: I/dalvikvm-heap(362): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.705MB for 1286224-byte allocation
01-18 13:33:45.135: D/dalvikvm(362): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 25% free 9849K/13063K, paused 28ms
01-18 13:33:45.225: D/dalvikvm(362): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4K, 25% free 9879K/13063K, paused 2ms+13ms
01-18 13:33:45.635: D/dalvikvm(362): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1369K, 30% free 9190K/13063K, paused 27ms
01-18 13:33:45.645: I/dalvikvm-heap(362): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.285MB for 1286224-byte allocation
01-18 13:33:45.695: D/dalvikvm(362): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5K, 21% free 10441K/13063K, paused 27ms
01-18 13:33:45.795: D/dalvikvm(362): GC_CONCURRENT freed 46K, 17% free 10921K/13063K, paused 2ms+4ms
01-18 13:33:45.895: D/dalvikvm(362): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2126K, 28% free 9442K/13063K, paused 27ms
01-18 13:33:45.895: I/dalvikvm-heap(362): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.531MB for 1286224-byte allocation
01-18 13:33:45.965: D/dalvikvm(362): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5K, 19% free 10693K/13063K, paused 2ms+3ms
01-18 13:33:46.505: I/ActivityManager(183): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.settings/.Settings} from pid 362
01-18 13:33:46.645: D/OpenGLRenderer(362): Flushing caches (mode 0)
01-18 13:33:46.705: W/InputManagerService(183): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4139b200 (uid=10023 pid=362)
01-18 13:33:46.725: D/OpenGLRenderer(362): Flushing caches (mode 1)
01-18 13:33:49.205: I/ManageApplications(4752): onCreateOptionsMenu in ManageApplications{4109d208 #2 id=0x10202d4}: com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder@41076b88
01-18 13:33:49.365: I/ManageApplications(4752): onCreateOptionsMenu in ManageApplications{4109d208 #2 id=0x10202d4}: com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder@41076b88
01-18 13:33:50.005: D/dalvikvm(865): GC_CONCURRENT freed 415K, 8% free 6548K/7111K, paused 1ms+2ms
01-18 13:33:50.165: D/AlarmReceiver(4890): onReceive
```

As you can see there is a big gap between 13:28:09 (unplug) and 13:33:16 (re-plug). Seems like nothing happened in between. To be sure that this is not a logging issue, every time the alarm is going of I write a simple timestamp to a file. This file is looking like this:

```
Fri Jan 18 13:25:50 MEZ 2013
Fri Jan 18 13:26:20 MEZ 2013
Fri Jan 18 13:26:50 MEZ 2013
Fri Jan 18 13:27:20 MEZ 2013
Fri Jan 18 13:27:50 MEZ 2013
Fri Jan 18 13:33:16 MEZ 2013
Fri Jan 18 13:33:20 MEZ 2013
Fri Jan 18 13:33:50 MEZ 2013
```

Same gap here...

Any ideas what I doing wrong?

Comment: What device are you running this on?

Comment: Device is a Trekstor SurfTab breeze 7.0 with Android 4.0.4

Comment: OK, I have never heard of that. Suffice it to say, what you have should be fine, suggesting that the issue is the device and hacks to its firmware. You might play around in your device's settings and see if there's any sort of super-aggressive power-saving mode that you may have on, where if you turn it off your code starts working.

Comment: Did you tried this on another device? To rule out perks assotiated with certain android firmware

Comment: I tried on a Nexus 7 with 4.2. Seems to work there

Comment: @CommonsWare: It works if I use the app "Wake Lock". But I thought that the AlarmManager wakes the device himself. It seems possible that this is a firmware issue

Comment: "But I thought that the AlarmManager wakes the device himself" -- it does, if you use a `_WAKEUP`-style alarm.